# Wait table view load until an NSString is populated

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an `UITableview` which has a description cell populated by an `NSString`, ok. But the problem is that the `UITableView` delegate methods are called before the code I use to download the description so it doesn't loads. How can I do something to solve this? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `[self.tableView reloadData];` when the download finished.

Comment: nice! but now I have a problem, the text which is added shows ok on nslog, but on the cell shows badly as it shows strange characters on the start of the text, cutting over 10 letters of it, what could make this happen?

Comment: will ask the new problem on a new question, thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the content to appear until you've downloaded, maintain a boolean flag and return 0 rows until the content has been downloaded.